# Remotely connect to MySQL database that's hosted on AWS

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I recently installed a LAMP stack on an ec2 instance that's running Ubuntu Linux. I followed the instructions found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu). I also installed `phpmyadmin`. To the best of my knowledge, while I was installing MySQL, I answered `no` when prompted to answer the question `Disallow root login remotely?` I could be mistaken though. I've read elsewhere that in order to allow root login remotely, I would need to edit the `mysql .conf` file found in the `/etc` folder somewhere and edit the `bridge` setting.

I've tried connecting by doing the following:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('ec-2 ip address', 'root', 'root', 'db_name');

if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error($con);
    die;
}
```

This is the error message I get when I connect:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '54.201.165.105' (61)
```

Comment: By default, all ports on ec2 instances are filewalled. Did you make an exception for MySQL (TCP 3306) ?

Comment: No, I didn't. How would I do that?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: Okay, I edited the inbound rules accordingly and it still won't let me connect.

Comment: Hmmm. What's the error?

Comment: Can't connect to MySQL server on '54.201.165.105' (61)

Comment: What shows up if you run `netstat -tln | grep 3306`?

Comment: You also need to make sure the root user in mysql allows for the host to connect from outside localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up answering this myself after just doing a little bit of research. Turns out that the security groups pn AWS had nothing to do with the problem. I had to go to the file at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and comment out the line that read `bind_address = 127.0.0.1`. Then I had to execute an SQL statement in phpmyadmin that went like this

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Thanks for all of the help though, guys. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need modify the AWS Security Group for the instance and set firewall rules to allow 3306 inbound traffic as well as modify the OS firewall rules to allow the same traffic.